# Usando o TvideoImage para capturar imagem da webCam

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, imagem

Estou utilizando o componente `TvideoImage` para capturar imagem através da *webCam*, porém estou com problema, foi criado um aplicativo que permite que tire fotos dos clientes para cadastro, o aplicativo foi incorporado no sistema principal para tirar fotos dos clientes, quando eu abro o aplicativo pelo sistema, na primeira vez funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu fecho e tento abrir novamente, quando eu clico no botão ligar a imagem fica em branco.

Código no evento `OnCreate`:

```
fVideoImage := TVideoImage.Create;
bActivated := False;

DeviceList := TStringList.Create;
fVideoImage.GetListOfDevices(DeviceList);
cbListaCameras.Items := DeviceList;
DeviceList.Free;
```

Código usado para ligar a câmera:

```
procedure TFormCamera.btnLigarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  camDevice: string;
begin
  try
     if not(bActivated)then
     begin
        camDevice := trim(cbListaCameras.Items.Strings[cbListaCameras.ItemIndex]);
        if(camDevice = '')then
        begin
           ShowMessage('Atenção, informe o dispositivo!');
           cbListaCameras.SetFocus;
           Exit;
        end;

        fVideoImage.SetDisplayCanvas(imgCamera.Canvas);
        fVideoImage.VideoStart(camDevice);
        bActivated := True;

        lblCameraStatus.Caption := 'Ligada';
        lblCameraStatus.Font.Color := clGreen;

     end else
        MessageDlg('Atenção, camera já está ligada!', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);>>

  except
     bActivated := False;
     lblCameraStatus.Caption := 'Desligada';
     lblCameraStatus.Font.Color := clRed;
     ShowMessage('Atenção, erro ao tentar ligar a camera!');
  end;
end;
```

Código usado no botão para fechar:

```
fVideoImage.VideoStop;
bActivated := false;
imgCamera.Picture := nil;
//imgCamera.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(nil);
Close;
```